# Locate position in sorted vector, fast

Tags: matlab, performance

I have a sorted vector in matlab, call it `F`, for this example say it is given as:

```
F = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

I do also have an arbitrary matrix `A` with elements in the interval 0-10 say:

```
 A = [1.5,9.1,5.2;2.3,0.4,7.9];
```

Then I am interested in the matrix `I` which for each entry in `A` tells me which interval in `F` it belongs to, given as the lower bound, in this case:

```
I = [1,9,5;2,0,7];
```

I know, in this case, it can be obtained by rounding down, but I am looking for the general case. I do also already have a piece of code solving this for me, which is:

```
I = zeros(size(A));
X(A<F(1)) = 0;
for i = 2:length(F)
   X(A<F(i) & A>F(i-1)) = i-1;
end
end
```

But, at this point, I check all entries in `A` for every `i`, even though the entries only satisfy the condition once.

So my problem here is to find a more efficient way to do this. First of all to avoid checking the same entries multiple times, but maybe also utilising that the vector `F` is sorted.

I have also tried using `arrayfun(@(a) find(a>=F,1)-1,A);` however this is around 100 times slower than the logic version above.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does the job, and is probably quite fast:

```
result = reshape(sum(bsxfun(@lt, F(:), A(:).'), 1), size(A));
```

I'm assuming the intervals are defined as (*a*,*b*]. For [*a*,*b*) replace `@lt` by `@le`.

It may be faster to do some sort of [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), exploiting the fact that the vector is sorted. It is possible that [`histcounts`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) does that internally. The third output gives what you want:

```
[~, ~, result] = histcounts(A, F);
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is basically what happens internally, of my line `X(A<F(i) & A>F(i-1)) = i-1;` so they are equally fast. However, the `histcounts` is a brilliant idea and reduces the running time with ~90%. I will leave it unanswered until tomorrow if anyone has a better method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works with float and int inputs.
values that are out of the range of interval interpolated as `NaN`, So it should be decided what can be done with thode values before to apply interpolation.

Using `interp` with option `nearest` apply nearest neighbor interpolation to data.

```
function out = histcount3(v , interval)
    %compute center of bins
    centers = interval(1:end-1) + diff(interval)/2;
    %apply nearest neighbor interpolation
    out = interp1(centers,interval(1:end-1),v(:),'nearest');
end
```

If intervals are of integer typed and the range of interval is reasonable a possible fast solution is :

```
function out = histcount2(v , interval)
    v= max(interval(1),v);
    v=min(interval(end),v);
    count= diff(interval);
    count(end) = count(end)+1;
    r = repelem(interval(1:end-1), count);
    out = r(floor(v)-interval(1)+1);
end
```

As before it should be decided  what can be done with values that are out of the range. I replace those valuse with min and max of interval.
I did a test in Octave but Octave doesn't has `histcount` for it a timing of `hist`  function provided that I think it has the same algorithm as `histcount` but with different results. You may run the benchmark with `histcount` to get proper results:

```
F = unique(randi([1000 100000],1,1000));
A = rand(100000,3)*101000;
disp('------histcount2:--------')
tic
    reshape(histcount2(A(:),F),size(A));
toc
disp('------histcount3:--------')
tic
    reshape(histcount3(A(:),F),size(A));
toc
disp('------hist:--------')
tic
    hist(A(:),F);
toc
disp('------bsxfun:--------')
tic
    reshape(sum(bsxfun(@le, F(:), A(:).'), 1), size(A));
toc
```

**Result**:

```
------histcount2:repelem--------
Elapsed time is 0.00749207 seconds.
------histcount3:interpolation--------
Elapsed time is 0.042104 seconds.
------hist:--------
Elapsed time is 0.135928 seconds.
------bsxfun:--------
Elapsed time is 0.516705 seconds.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `F` is not restricted to be integers, thus `count` consists of floats and using `repelem` with a non-integer second argument returns an error. Is it possible to fix?

Comment: I am quite interested in a fix because it would seem like your solution is another ten times faster than the `histcounts`.

Comment: @NickyMattsson let me I think a better solution is available

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by matlab, a slight improvement to @Luis Mendo suggestion should be to use `discretize`.

From the documentation, https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/discretize.html

> The behavior of discretize is similar to that of the histcounts function. Use histcounts to find the number of elements in each bin. On the other hand, use discretize to find which bin each element belongs to (without counting).

Thus turning the line of code into:

```
I = discretize(A,F)-1;
```

Though one has to specify a minimum in the variable `F`. So continuing my example from the original post, it would turn `F` into:

```
F = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

However, my testruns shows that `histcounts` is consistently a little bit faster.